# VMWare to VirtualBox - no networking

Tags: networking, virtualbox, vmware

I converted my VMWare Windows Server 2003 image to a OVF using ovftool. I then imported it in VirtualBox - it worked fine except there is no networking. I tried NAT, Bridged Adapter and Host Only. But in all 3, I don't get any network connection - When I run ipconfig, it returns an empty output.

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on ipconfig not reporting a network adapter,

- Remove VMware Tools (if installed) and Install [VirtualBox Guest
  additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html) for network drivers.
- Then check the Control Panel -    Network adapters / Device Manager
  to make sure your network card is    present.